# Calculate the width of a bubble which expands when clicking

Tags: html, css

I am stuck looking for a solution via CSS without using javascript for this.

I have a bubble in the second column, which expands when clicking on it. I want it to expand to the first column regardless of the width of the screen.

This is the CSS for the container:

```
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 75% 25%;
}
```

This one for both columns container:

```
:is(column1,column2){
  position: relative;
}
```

And this for bubble:

```
.bubble{
  position: absolute;
  left: 5rem;
}
```

Approach when clicking on the bubble:

```
.bubble--editing {
  transform: translate(-43vw);
  width: calc(100vw - 80rem);
}
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Heres the codepen with the bubble collapsed. I need deploy it to the beginning of the first column:
https://codepen.io/Barcos/pen/NWOwxXZ

Comment: Please make your code into a runnable snippet. In particular we need your HTML structure and what are column1 and column2? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: is it possible for you to give some code in stackbliz

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/vilola/pen/MWPOeGx

As the .bubble is inside of the .containers grid column with 25% width, when you want the .bubble to have 100% width of the whole container, you have to set its width to 400%.

Because 4 * 25% of the container = 100% of the container. And 25% of the container = 100% for the right column. So 4 * 100% = 400% width on the .bubble would make the .bubble have the full width of the .container.
Then the .bubble needs to be on the right edge of the column, otherwise it will overflow out of the container on the left side. (Or you can calc the correct width from the 400% base)

```
.bubble {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bubble--editing{
  border-color: green;
  
  /* 100% is equal to 25% of the whole .container (based on the previously set grid-template-columns in .container), so if needed to have 100% of the container =  4 * 100%  */
  width: 400%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Works fine in the aplication.